# Finding a Devices Security Mode

Tags: security, bluetooth

I am conducting a project into bluetooth security and would appreciate if someone could clear this up for me. When is comes to finding out which security mode a device implements where would find find this out? Would it be in the drivers for the device or stored on the hardware?

Comment: What do you mean for security mode? Bluetooth allows for many security levels. A device can use different of them depending on the situation

Comment: What I mean is how can I find out which mode a device is using one connected?

Comment: Regardless of whether you are using BLE or Bluetooth Classic, the security modes are decided by the profiles. See for example the Blood Pressure profile at page 22 https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=243125&_ga=2.124269066.141840229.1510935813-805712375.1510935813